# Low output voltage on buck converter

Tags: ltspice, buck

I am making use of the LM2678 adjustable version switching regulator in the design of a 5.5V buck converter. I made use of the design equations detailed here: [lm2678 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2678.pdf)

For the following design constraints:

1. Vout: 5.5v
2. Vinmax: 15v
3. ILoadmax: 3A

I worked through the design equations to obtain the circuit values shown below:

[image: buck circuit]
Next I imported the Spice model for the LM2678-adj from the TI website into LTSpice. I calculated a load resistance as \$R = \frac{V}{I} = \frac{5.5}{3} = 1.83 \Omega\$ and did a transient analysis simulation for 2ms. The result with input voltage (red) and output voltage (blue) is shown below along with LT spice schematic:

[image: LT]
[image: Buck Converter Transient Sim]

The output voltage value is 1.83mV. Removing the load results in an output voltage of just over 2V. The datasheet suggests a typical feedback voltage of 1.21V however when I measure the voltage between the feedback node and ground under load I get 367.17186µV. The output voltage is related to the input voltage and output resistors via the following formula: \$V_{out} = V_{fb}(1+\frac{R8}{R9})\$ hence the reason the output voltage is so low is because of the low feedback voltage. What is causing this feedback voltage to be so low and how can i fix this?

My goal with this buck converter is to have a stable 5.5V out and be able to draw a maximum of 3A from it at this voltage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit:

I've discovered that the spice model provided on TIs website is setup for the fixed 3.3v version of this IC. It means that the internal feedback resistors are incorrectly defined. I tried changing the values for the internal R1 and R2 feedback resistors to match those for the adjustable version (found on page 10 of the datasheet) however I still get the same error. There may be more incorrect definitions.

Comment: Is the ground wire actually attached to the LM2678 model?

Comment: @rdtsc I've double checked and it is connected. I've spotted something else however. The TI spice model provided is for the fixed 3.3V version. This means that the internal feedback resistances in the spice definition are for the 3.3v and not the adjustable version. I've set R2 to open and R1 to 0 for the adjustable version as indicated in the datasheet but I'm still getting the same result. There are maybe more parameters that need to change.

Comment: Why not use TI's online simulator? I think it even has SPICE export but I'm not sure. For this case it should work nicely. http://www.ti.com/tools-software/design-center/webench-power-designer.html

Comment: @JanDorniak I've been playing around with it for about an hour now after your suggestion. It gives just about the exact same values for components as the ones I obtained doing the calculations by hand. I just can't make sense of the simulation results... I run a steady state analysis and the y-axis is in -0.1v increments?

Comment: I replicated your results - my best bet is that there is a bug in the SPICE model or something... At this point I would take it to the TI forums - https://e2e.ti.com/ as this results seem a bit abnormal. You might also consider adding the info about TI's simulator giving similar results in your question.

Comment: @JanDorniak Thanks for your help. I have made a post to e2e.ti.com. Hopefully someday in the future I will be able to simulate this simple little circuit.

Comment: @Blargian all the more considering the name of the series... Btw: why not use a synchronous converter? With integrated switches.

Comment: @JanDorniak that is definitely something I could take a look at. Could you recommend an IC for that purpose?

Comment: @Blargian Apart from TI, one we use is Richtek's RT2862. They have few distributors but are available online and have a working simulator at richtek.transim.com - logging in is quirky but the sims work. Or try another of TI's parts - not all will have broken SPICE models. They had a nice table but I can't find it.

Comment: Trying to simulate a similar circuit with the 5V version. The ON_OFF pin should float according to the datasheet. Also, I think 2 ms are too few for Vout to ramp up fully, but if you increase the end time of your simulation you might hit an infinite "def con" loop after around 2.7 ms, which is where I'm stuck at right now.